# How to remove user using Django Allauth API?

Tags: django, django-allauth

When a user in my Django app cancels their account, I set `is_active=False` in the auth_user table.

However, if that use signs up again, Allauth complains that the email is already in use, even if I manually change the email field to something else in the auth_user table.

Allauth is going by the email addresses in the 'account_emailaddress' table.  So what's the correct API call to tell Allauth to forget that email, while also setting the auth_user table to not active?  Is it safe to delete the entry from the 'account_emailaddress' table myself?

Or maybe there's a signal that allauth uses to listen for the record in the auth_user table being completely deleted by my app, and just unsetting 'is_active' isn't enough?

I see no such signal listed in the docs, though there is one for changing the email.

In short, what's the Allauth way to a) suspend and/or b) delete a user?

I'm not concerned about social accounts at the moment, though one will be used later.

The following answer implies it's enough to set `is_active=False` as I describe above, but I've found that more is needed if you want to allow that email to be reused.

[How to allow user to delete account in django allauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38047408/how-to-allow-user-to-delete-account-in-django-allauth)

Comment: Have you set `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "username"` I think you have not set this or you have set this to email ?

Comment: Yes, ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD is set to 'email', and ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True.  Is it not possible to have it set to email without that email being prohibited in perpetuity after the user deletes the account?